# Check if a value starts with one of the value of a column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Hi I'd like to check if a value starts with one of the value of a another column.

```
t1  | t2  
----------  
3253 | 123  
1234 | 000  
9876 | 932
```

So here for example I should have True for the value 1234 because it starts with `123`.
I should have false for the other values.

I can't find any solutions.
Thank you in advance for you help !

I already tried :

```
t1 LIKE (t2 || '%')  
starts_with(t1,t2)  
starts_with(t1, (select t2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `t1 LIKE (t2 || '%')`  should be able to get you close to what I think you need, however maybe you are just missing a bit of script logic?

Ignoring any platform specific language (I don't use Big Query), this is just to show the logic that might help you get the result you desire

With the data as:

```
create table my_table
(t1 number,
 t2 number);
insert into my_table values(3253,123);
insert into my_table values(1234,000);
insert into my_table values(9876,932);
```

You can use a case statement wrapped in a sum to count the matches using `like t2||'%`. Any value in the resulting column that is 1 or greater should be read as True, and value of 0 as False.

```
SELECT a.t1,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN a.t1 LIKE b.t2
                            || '%' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS starts_with
FROM   my_table a,
       my_table b
GROUP  BY a.t1
```

This gives the output

```
T1  STARTS_WITH
9876    0
1234    1
3253    0
```

Answer (score 0):

That works for me :

```
-- To match your example
WITH T (t1,t2) AS
(
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (3253,123),(1234,000),(9876,932))t(t1,t2)
)

-- What your query should like
SELECT TAB1.t1,TAB1.t2, Tab2.t2
FROM T AS Tab1
CROSS JOIN T AS Tab2
WHERE CAST(TAB1.t1 AS STRING) LIKE (CAST(TAB2.t2 AS STRING) + '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to try

```
select * except(check), 
  regexp_contains(t1, check) 
from (
  select *, r'^' || string_agg(t2, '|') over() check
  from your_table
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Hi Mikhail,
I tried this on my data set, the problem is that  on Big Querry I got the following error : 
'Resources exceeded during query execution'.
Do you think there is a way to optimize this ?
BR